# Objective-C compile error: Invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: objective-c

```
-(void)updateCharacterStatsForArmor:(RKArmor *)armor withWeapons:(RKWeapon *)weapon withHealthEffect:(int)healtheffect
{
    if (armor != nil){
        self.character.health = self.character.health - self.character.armor.health + armor.health;
        self.character.armor = armor;
    }
    else if (weapon != nil){
        // The problematic line:
        self.character.damage = self.character.damage - self.character.weapon.damage + weapon.damage;

        self.character.weapon = weapon;
    }
    else if (healtheffect != 0){
        self.character.health = self.character.health + healtheffect;
    }
    else {
        self.character.health = self.character.health + self.character.armor.health;
        self.character.damage = *(self.character.damage + self.character.weapon.damage);
    }
}

@end
```

The line with the error is marked in the code snippet. The error says `invalid operand to binary expression int int*`.

Would It be best to restart the whole thing?

Comment: What is RKArmor, RKWeapon, how are defined their `damage` property? The last line has a `*`, so why should the line with your issue not have it? It does not seem logic.

Comment: it is my RKArmor and RKWeapon are my armor and weapon classes and I do not know why it is not working

Comment: That what I guess, but you should show the code of them, at least how are defined `damage` for each of them.

Comment: ok here is the codeing #alot of code

Comment: RKTile *tile1 = [[RKTile alloc] init];
    tile1.story = @" Commander, the enemy has invaded our ship. We need your help to fight them and end the war. Take this pistol to get started";
    tile1.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images-2.jpeg"];
    RKWeapon *pistolWeapon = [[RKWeapon alloc] init];
    pistolWeapon.name = @"Pistol";
    pistolWeapon.damage = 15;
    tile1.weapon = pistolWeapon;
    tile1.actionButtonName = @"Take the gun";

Comment: this is only some of it

Comment: In fact, we need more the .h than what you posted. And please put your code by editing your question, not in comment. Especially the line about the `damage` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You probably defined one of the damage properties you're using as an int* instead of int. Check your character and weapon classes for that. I'd suspect self.character.damage.

Answer (score 0):

If the line you indicated really is the problem, it looks like you've probably declared the `damage` property of the character class to return `int *` instead of `int`. It's easy to make that mistake because properties that point to objects are always pointers. `int`, however, is not an object type, so there's usually not need to store a pointer to one in a property.

The line you say is a problem is:

```
self.character.damage = self.character.damage - self.character.weapon.damage + weapon.damage;
```

But later on you have:

```
self.character.damage = *(self.character.damage + self.character.weapon.damage);
```

It looks like this second line is some kind of attempt to avoid a compiler error, but it doesn't seem to make a lot of sense. You'd only dereference the result of the addition if you were doing pointer arithmetic, but that doesn't make much sense for a property called `damage`.

To fix all this, take a look at your character class declaration. You'll probably see something like:

```
@property(...) int *damage;
```

Remove that `*` and make sure the attribute is `assign`, like this:

```
@property(assign) int damage;
```

Also, it's not clear how pirates are involved. Perhaps ye have been a mite hasty in makin' yer query? Arrr!

Comment: do how do I make so it later on does not become self.character.damage = *(self.character.damage + self.character.weapon.damage); ?

Comment: i was learning on udemy, it was a pirate game, but I made it into a diffrent theme

Comment: Added a bit on how to fix. If that works, review the docs on properties and make sure you understand the difference between an object and an `int`, and that you understand why the fix helped.

Comment: I looked there is no asterid by the damage the code in my character class looks like this

Comment: property (strong, nonatomic) RKArmor *armor;
property (strong, nonatomic) RKWeapon *weapon;
property (nonatomic) int health;
property (nonatomic) int damage;

Comment: Then what's the purpose of the `*` that dereferences the sum in the last line? That may in fact be the real error.

Comment: the purpose of the * for armor and weapon is so that the interface type cannot be statically allocated thing wont show up

Comment: i found out a way: self.character.damage = self.character.damage + self.character.weapon.damage - weapon.damage;

Comment: but when I do that and run the simulater it just messes it up

Comment: I was referring to the `*` in `*(self.character.damage + self.character.weapon.damage)`, which doesn't make any sense if `damage` returns `int`.